# Fullcalendar non-gregorian months

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, hebrew

I am looking for a way to display a fullcalenar month grid divided by Hebrew calendar months (Tishrei, Cheshvan etc.).

I managed to display the hebrew date within the cells of the month grid view using `dayCellContent` (including bootstrap classes):

```
//Array of letters representing the day of the month
const hebDateLetters = ['א', 'ב', 'ג', 'ד', 'ה', 'ו', 'ז', 'ח', 'ט', 'י', 'יא', 'יב', 'יג', 'יד', 'טו', 'טז', 'יז', 'יח', 'יט', 'כ', 'כא', 'כב', 'כג', 'כד', 'כה', 'כו', 'כז', 'כח', 'כט', 'ל',]; 

...

dayCellContent: (info)=>{
        var hebDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('he-IL-u-ca-hebrew', {day: 'numeric'}).format(info.date);
        var hebMonth = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('he-IL-u-ca-hebrew', {month: 'long'}).format(info.date);

        //Container element
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        container.setAttribute("class", "container p-1"); 

        //First row element
        const elRow1 = document.createElement("div");
        elRow1.setAttribute("class", 'row m-0 w-100');
        const elCol1 = document.createElement("div");
        elCol1.setAttribute("class", 'col p-0');
        elCol1.innerText = hebDate !=1 ? hebDateLetters[hebDate-1] : hebDateLetters[hebDate-1] + " " + hebMonth; // Condition to display Hebrew month name on first day of the month
        elRow1.appendChild(elCol1);

        //Second row element
        const elRow2 = document.createElement("div");
        elRow2.setAttribute("class", 'row m-0 w-100');
        const elCol2 = document.createElement("div");
        elCol2.setAttribute("class", 'col p-0 c-date');
        elCol2.innerText = info.date.getDate();
        elRow2.appendChild(elCol2);

        container.appendChild(elRow1);
        container.appendChild(elRow2);
        return {html: container.outerHTML};
      }
```

This is what I achived

[image: Calendar Image]

My next step would be to display the months according to the Hebrew calendar. I've been trying to build a custom view as discribed here: [Custom view with JS](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js), but I'm not fully sure how to use this to achive what I'm looking for.

Comment: which version of full calendar?

Comment: I'm using version 6.1.9

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use the locale as hebrew. Full calendar already has that option.

Add reference to that

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@ 6.1.10/locales/he.js"></script>
<script>
new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    locale: 'he',
    //...
});
</script>
```

Combining with your code gives the result

```js
const hebDateLetters = ['א', 'ב', 'ג', 'ד', 'ה', 'ו', 'ז', 'ח', 'ט', 'י', 'יא', 'יב', 'יג', 'יד', 'טו', 'טז', 'יז', 'יח', 'יט', 'כ', 'כא', 'כב', 'כג', 'כד', 'כה', 'כו', 'כז', 'כח', 'כט', 'ל',];
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    locale: 'he',
    dayCellContent: (info)=>{
        var hebDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('he-IL-u-ca-hebrew', {day: 'numeric'}).format(info.date);
        var hebMonth = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('he-IL-u-ca-hebrew', {month: 'long'}).format(info.date);

        //Container element
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        container.setAttribute("class", "container p-1"); 

        //First row element
        const elRow1 = document.createElement("div");
        elRow1.setAttribute("class", 'row m-0 w-100');
        const elCol1 = document.createElement("div");
        elCol1.setAttribute("class", 'col p-0');
        elCol1.innerText = hebDate !=1 ? hebDateLetters[hebDate-1] : hebDateLetters[hebDate-1] + " " + hebMonth; // Condition to display Hebrew month name on first day of the month
        elRow1.appendChild(elCol1);

        //Second row element
        const elRow2 = document.createElement("div");
        elRow2.setAttribute("class", 'row m-0 w-100');
        const elCol2 = document.createElement("div");
        elCol2.setAttribute("class", 'col p-0 c-date');
        elCol2.innerText = info.date.getDate();
        elRow2.appendChild(elCol2);

        container.appendChild(elRow1);
        container.appendChild(elRow2);
        return {html: container.outerHTML};
      }
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.10/index.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@ 6.1.10/locales/he.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question. I'm not looking for Hebrew names of gregorian months, I'm looking for a way to dispaly the months according to the Hebrew-Jewish calendar. Now we are in the month of Tevet which started on Wednsday 13/12/23. So I want that date to be the beggining of the month.

Comment: ah. I understand, we have this state calendar(native language) which starts around mid month here too.  I am unaware of a solution yet, but will research it. do you have an api that gets the current jewish dates of the english month?

Comment: tried this? https://gist.github.com/mjradwin/0ebb62ac6fa0abf23964

Comment: @Navven J
It seems to me that the code from GitHub adds the dates as events in my fullcalendar, which I already managed to do with `dayCellContent`. 
To get the Hebrew day by Gregorian date I’ve used `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: I can loop through the days of the Gregorian month to find the first day of the Hebrew month